# What type to use for in-memory image data in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

I'm trying to model a `data Photo` and wondering what type to use for the image data:

```
data Photo =
  Photo
  { photoUploaderId :: AccountId
  , photoWidth :: Int
  , photoHeight :: Int
  , photoData :: ByteString
  }
```

I'm using `Data.ByteString` here. Are there any better choice?

Background: I'm going to store the image data in a database, and retrieve and send it over a network connection. On inserting the photo into the database for the first time, I may need to manipulate it a bit, like scaling, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're going to access arbitrary pixels of photos use an [unboxed array](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array-Unboxed.html). It will give you O(1) indexing and a minimal space overhead. `UArray (Int, Int) Word32` should be what you are looking for. Remeber that unboxed arrays are strict. If you're looking for non-strictness use an [`Array`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array.html#t:Array), but keep in mind that values of pixels will be boxed which degrades the performance.

Another types of similar capabilities and worth considering are [vectors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.5).

On the other hand, if you are *not* going to manipulate pixels and you'll treat the image just as a blob, `ByteString` is a good choice. That's what it was designed for: blobs of binary data.

In summary: manipulate using either `Array` or `Vector`, store and transfer as `ByteString`.

Comment: Thanks. What if I just need to send the image data over a network connection? I'm not going to manipulate the pixels on my own.

Comment: Yeah I think mostly I just need a blob then. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Generally speaking, UArray is a good choice. It depends on the photo format, how you're going to read the image, and what kind of processing you do with it. I find the Codec.Image.DevIL library to be handy for photo processing. Here's an example converting a JPEG image to PNG.

```
import Codec.Image.DevIL

main = do
  ilInit
  img <- readImage "test.jpeg"
  writeImage "test.png" img
```

The readImage function has this signature.

```
readImage :: FilePath -> IO (UArray (Int, Int, Int) Word8)
```

And it returns an RGBA array. Indices are (row,column,color-channel). So `IO (UArray (Int, Int, Int) Word8)` would be a good choice if you're going to use that library.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question with more detailed background. Can I use Codec.Image.DevIL if the image data is retrieved from a database?

Comment: It looks like Codec.Image.DevIL only has support for reading from a file, so I don't think you could use it to read from a database.

Comment: You should check out JuicyPixels: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/JuicyPixels/2.0.2/doc/html/Codec-Picture.html and in particular you can see functions like 'decodeImage' that work on a raw ByteString. (you even have decodeGif, decodePng, decodeJpeg, decodeBitmap -- all working on a in-memory ByteString)

Comment: Note that DevIL also has a nice binding via `repa` - [as repa-devil](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/repa-devil/0.3.2.2/doc/html/Data-Array-Repa-IO-DevIL.html), allowing you to write parallel image operations easily.